# Why is Google Chrome websocket sending me smiley faces, not a mirror?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I'm testing pings and pongs in my websocket application. I pinged a websocket client in Chrome.

Google Chrome sent me back smiley faces. The data was: `☺☻♥´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢`

In Scala, here is how I am generating the byte array:

```
val byteData = (new String(Array[Byte](1,2,3,-1,-2,-127).map(_.toChar))).toCharArray.map(_.toByte)
```

Can anyone confirm is this really the data that Google needs to be sending back? Does Google Chrome not mirror the bytes I send to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are getting the same thing back, and this is just an artifact of how you are printing out the binary data that you receive. It looks like your encoding/font is similar to this:

http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/bullet-alt-codes.php

Comment: fascinating, i didn't think it would be a related to my console program (using the open-source command line in Win7) thanks for letting me know!